# uiwebview live bytes keep going up?

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-leaks, uiwebview, profiler

I have a RSS feed reader app that I'm running through profiler, and I'm noticing that whenever I load a uiwebview and pop it from my navigation controller, my Live Bytes goes up by a small amount (.10-.40MB). I'd expect Live Bytes to stay where it was at before the uiwebview was launched. Does this indicate that I'm leaking something or is this normal for uiwebview objects?

Comment: Post some code so we can take a look.

Comment: code is too large.. have a bunch of things in my uiview but im nilling out everything i create in viewdidunload

Comment: You don't give enough detail to know what's going on without showing some code. It's like diagnosing a medical disease without knowing the symptoms. Are you using ARC? If not, are you releasing the `UIWebView` after adding it to the `UINavigationController`?

Comment: It's entirely possible this is simply due to internal webkit caches. Is the growth unbounded, or does it eventually stop happening if you push and pop enough webviews?

Comment: yes I'm using ARC. I'm poping from the navigation stack, so it should be released. I'm thinking this is due to webkit caching. Let me see if the growth is unbounded...

Comment: @user1492272 If you're freeing a bunch of stuff in `viewDidUnload`, you might want to put a NSLog statement in there and you might find it's not being called like you think it should. You might want to consider moving some of this memory freeing logic into `dealloc`.

Comment: it seems the growth si unbounded.. running profiler, i see trivial leaks (few malloc 48 leaks). any ideas whats going on?

Comment: robert, im seeing very few trivial leaks in profiler so unload is def. being called. but my live bytes keep going up steadily...

Comment: the leaks are occuring in libsystem_c.dylib.. googling suggests this might be a bug w/ apple

Comment: @user1492272 (1) I've definitely seen the libsystem_c.dylib leaks, but when I experienced it, it was tens of bytes, not the tens of kilobytes; (2) I'm very surprised that you're seeing `viewDidLoad` being called, because in many scenarios it's simply won't be. Maybe you've got a scenario where it is being called, but I'd be surprised. Regardless, it is a mistake to rely upon `viewDidLoad` for cleanup and not release stuff in `dealloc`. In answer to your main question, no, it is _not_ normal for UIWebView to leak like you describe, so it's probably something in your code. Good luck!

Comment: Robert, I found a number of other people having the same issues. Does seem to be a webview thing, unfortunately.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2339279/memory-leak-tool-tells-me-zero-leaks-but-memory-footprint-keeps-rising

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the basis of your comments, I went back and examined my webview to see if there were any leaks. Profiler didn't report any leaks, but the number of Live Bytes was definitely going up a small amount every time I presented and subsequently dismissed the webview. In my case, Live Bytes was going up by 40-50kb each time, not 100-400kb, but nonetheless, it was definitely growing. My earlier comments were based upon leaks identified by Profiler's Leaks tool (e.g. the Twitter.framework definitely has a known identified leak but it's tens of bytes, not kilobytes). I generally don't track Live Bytes, so I apologize if I misled you.

So, in answer to your question, I guess it is not unusual for memory to be consumed as you present and dismiss webview controls. I would not be inclined, though, to consider the growth in Live Bytes a leak unless the Profiler is also reporting a leak in the Leaks tool.